# Harmonic Maximum modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

So, i am starting to solve some exercises of complex analysis, and i am a little rusty, so if anyone could help me with this exercise.
I think that if i just can prove the mean value theorem for harmonic functions, that would be enough...but i am getting some troubles with that

Let $u$ be an harmonic function on $\Omega=\{z:|z|<R\}$ and continuous on the closure of $\Omega$ such that $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Prove that $u\equiv 0$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: Have you read about the [Cauchy Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula)?

Comment: @qaphla Yes i did, but the version i know requires f to be holomorphic...wich is not the case

Comment: The definition of harmonic that I know of would imply holomorphic, but it's quite possibly not the right one. How is harmonic defined in this case?

Comment: @qaphla harmonic is $\Delta (f)=0$ (Laplacian equal to 0)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [Green's identities](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities). You can alternatively recall that harmonic functions are locally the real part of a holomorphic function.

Comment: Harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be viewed as real parts of holomorphic functions. However, in other dimensions, a different approach needs to be used.

Comment: Of course, @robjohn ... I offered the second sentence because of things the OP said and the complex analysis tag. :P My first sentence is going to work in all dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

A corollary to maximum modulus theorem, (or to the open mapping theorem) says that a harmonic function attains its maximum and minimum value on the boundary of a domain. 
Since it is zero on the boundary, the rest is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The [Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) says that
$$
\int_{B(r,x)}\Delta f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\partial B(r,x)}\nabla f(y)\cdot\vec{n}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma(y)\tag{1}
$$
The right side of $(1)$ is the area of $\partial B(r,x)$ times the rate of change of the mean value of $f$ over $\partial B(r,x)$. Since $\Delta f(y)=0$ for harmonic functions, we get that the mean value of $f$ over $\partial B(r,x)$ is constant. Thus, we have the [Mean Value Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property).

The Mean Value Property implies
$$
|f(x)|\le\frac1{|B(r,x)|}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(y)|\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}
$$
Suppose that $|f|$ attains its maximum at $x_0$ in the interior of $K$ and $B(r,x_0)\subset K$. The existence of a $y\in B(r,x_0)$ so that $|f(y)|\lt|f(x_0)|$ contradicts $(2)$ since $f$ is continuous. Therefore, $|f(y)|=|f(x_0)|$ for all $y\in B(r,x_0)$. By covering a path from $x_0$ to any $x$ in the interior of $K$ with a sequence of balls such that each ball contains the center of the next, we get that $|f(x)|=|f(x_0)|$ for all $x\in K$. Thus, we have the [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Therefore, if a harmonic function is $0$ on $\partial K$, it must be $0$ on all of $K$.